# Is there a way to save a Keras model build in tensorflow 2.0 from Model Sub classing API?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

Is there a way to save the entire model build using tf.keras Model subclassing API after the training is done? I know we can use save_weights to save the weights only, but is there a way to save the whole model so that I may use it for prediction later when I do not have the code available?

```
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):

def __init__(self, num_classes=10):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__(name='my_model')
    self.num_classes = num_classes
    # Define your layers here.
    self.dense_1 = layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')
    self.dense_2 = layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid')

def call(self, inputs):
    # Define your forward pass here,
    # using layers you previously defined (in `__init__`).
    x = self.dense_1(inputs)
    return self.dense_2(x)

model = MyModel(num_classes=10)

# The compile step specifies the training configuration.
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001),
          loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(data, labels, batch_size=32, epochs=5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following steps for saving model after training, loading and inference:

**Save Model after training**

```
model.save(filepath="model")
# OR
tf.keras.models.save_model(model, filepath="model_")
```

**Load Saved Model**

```
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(filepath="model_")
```

**Prediction using Loaded model**

```
result = loaded_model.predict(test_db)
```

Comment: Will this also work for models created using the Model Subclassing API? As in for the example shown in the question above?

Comment: Yes it is. I have tried with your given code. Why don't you check out?

Comment: Will do it. Thanks

Comment: It worked...Thanks a lot...for some reason the documentation on the tensorflow website (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize) says that you cannot save the standalone model for subclassing API